# golang gitlab cicd in docker, but show sql:database is closed

Tags: docker, go

**docker sql:database is closed**

there are no idea, my location is pass the program, buid is ok, the mysql use ip connect.

it is not ok in docker, show sql:database is closed

```
err = db.MysqlDial(&config.Mysql)
defer db.Eloquent.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("dial mysql error", err)
}
```

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxKrt.png)

[.gitlab-ci.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRNgx.png)

Comment: Please elaborate your problem further. It's hard to understand what your problem is. If the software works, when you run it locally, but not when you run it locally within docker than there's likely a difference between your local environment and the one run in docker. This could include software versions used, as well as environment variables and configurations set

Comment: it works fine by go build it locally and take it to my server, but build it by gitlab-runner(cicd) will get this wrong.

Comment: On which step in GitLab does the build fail or has your problem already been solved?

Comment: the problem had be solved, The error code is caused by the wrong mirroring time zone of alpine

Comment: If you use kubernetes you should build image and run container in kubernetes deploying.

And in your dockerfile building go app code is absent, I see only swagger docs building code